# css: how to have a variable column size with text overflow ellipsis

Tags: html, css

This is starting to drive me nuts, any help appreciated!

I would like to have each `<li>` that isn't "fixed" to have a maximum width of say 150px, and a minimum width of say 10px, however when the browser is resized down, they should shrink to fix (and be equal in width).  I would also like the text within each non "fixed" `<li>` to have text-overflow: ellipsis.

I just can't seem to get this working, so far I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/546t8/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="fixed">Fixed Size</li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>this text is very very long and it goes on and on and on and on but does not wrap</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>short</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>one more tab</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>another tab</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 6px 0px;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
    width: 150px;

}

li > div {
     overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

}

li > div > span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li.fixed {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**UPDATE:** this shows what I'm after with the columns but as you can see the text isn't hidden with the ellipsis:

http://jsfiddle.net/546t8/9/

**UPDATE:** this is getting closer, but still no ellipsis :-(

http://jsfiddle.net/546t8/11/

**UPDATE: SOLVED** Solution posted below.

http://jsfiddle.net/AjZDx/2/

Comment: Can the HTML structure be changed?

Comment: @VimalStan yes, the html can be changed.

Comment: what do you need the ellipse for?  html will just break the text to fit into your li (once you remove white-space: nowrap;).  Would you prefer hiding part of the text to breaking the text to go an several lines?

Comment: @bjelli yes, the requirement is that the text does not wrap, and hides to the right with the ellipsis when there isn't enough room.

Comment: @magritte You're right, removed the answer. Will post one if I find the solution.

Comment: @VimalStan no worries, you actually pointed me in the right direction with table-layout: fixed, I posted my own solution, you don't want to know how long that took! Many thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm. May need IE 10 and above.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345158/variable-sized-column-with-ellipsis-in-a-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got this to work...  The solution was (no html change was required):

http://jsfiddle.net/AjZDx/2/

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 6px 0px;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
    min-width: 20px;
    width: 120px;
}

li.fixed {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul > li > div {
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 0px 0px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

ul > li > div > span {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that display: table and display: table-cell are a dead end: table layout will always use the maximum cell height necessary to show all the content (see below) - but you need the opposite. On the other hand table layout is good for using the horizontal space in the way you describe.

A wholly different approach would be to use some javascript library to do the layouting for you. There's tons of those. some example:

- http://masonry.desandro.com/ "pintrest like" layout of blocks
- http://www.datatables.net/ "data table" layouts
- http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/table_fixed_header.html  general layout
- and many more

p.s.

With float and simpler html you get the height but not the width you want:

```
<ul>
    <li class="fixed">Fixed Size</li>
    <li class="ellipsis">this text is very very long and it goes on and on and
on and on but does not wrap</li>
    <li>short</li>
    <li>one more tab</li>
    <li>another tab</li>
</ul>
```

and css

```
li {
    float:left;
    min-width: 10px;
}

li.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 200px;
}

li.fixed {
    width: 150px;
}
```

See this fiddle for a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/TxDfc/

Comment: I need the columns to be equal in width (the ones that aren't fixed), hence the display:table, display:table-cell. Is there another way I could achieve that? cheers.

Comment: cheers Bjelli, I have javascript solution that works (setting the width on the div's appears to kick the text-overflow:ellipsis into action), just thought it would be better if it's possible with pure css.