# Hide overflow of column with ellipsis, shrink other cols to fit content, don't set any table/col widths, and expand the table to fit within a div

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
  width: 250px;
}

table {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th {
  max-width: 175px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
th:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}
th:hover span {
  background-color: white;
}
td {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th><span>Short Header</span></th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Quite Long Header</span></th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><span>MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMassiveHeader</span></th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And here is an example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ptc3fL5/

Notice how the first column in the last row of the table is too wide to fit, so it overflows with an ellipsis. But if you hover over it, it expands to show the whole value.

However if I get rid of the `max-width` style of `th`, it all falls apart. The table no longer fits within the parent div. This is a problem because I would like to achieve this same effect without having to pre-specify the width.

My reason is that I want to make a generic utility class I can use in different tables in different responsive pages. In the general case, I don't know the width of the parent div (especially on responsive pages), I don't know the widths of the other columns in the table, and I don't want to have to go through and manually figure it out in every case and keep that up to date with every change.

I just want all the columns except the first to shrink as much as possible without overflow, and for the first to column expand as much as it can *while keeping the table inside the parent div* while hiding any overflow of its contents with an ellipsis at the end.

I realize there are about 5000 similar questions here, but at this point I think I've looked through all of them and still haven't found anything that works. [This is pretty close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345158/variable-sized-column-with-ellipsis-in-a-table), but doesn't respect the size of a wrapping div. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be wrong but I doubt it's possible without specifying some width somewhere. Have you tried `max-width: 20ch;` on the header? Does the 2nd column ever get longer than `value`?

Comment: The 2nd column can be either longer or shorter than `value`. There can also be more than 2 columns.

Comment: And just to be clear... when there are more than 2 columns, I want the extra columns all treated like the `value` column here (shrink as much as possible without overflowing, and then let the first column expand as much as possible but and hide its overflow).

Comment: I have just edited my answer below, please check it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were looking for. Check the snippet.

**Edit :** Add an absolute positioned div in first column with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and fix the width of other columns to 1px or 1% and make them `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  position: relative;
}

tr td:not(:first-child), tr th:not(:first-child){
    width:1%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.first-row{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th><div class="first-row">Header Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooon</div></th>
      <th>First Value</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div class="first-row"> Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog text</div></td>
      <td>Value two</td>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div class="first-row">Second Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog text</div></td>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><div class="first-row">Third Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooonooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog text</div></td>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>Value</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Why I got a downvote if the OP clearly specifies that `I just want all the columns except the first to shrink as much as possible without overflow, and for the first to column expand as much as it can while keeping the table inside the parent div while hiding any overflow of its contents with an ellipsis at the end.`

Comment: I'll give you an upvote to offset the downvote, but your answer isn't what I was looking for. I see https://i.imgur.com/ib4GhcS.png which is not doing this part - "all the columns except the first to shrink as much as possible without overflow" - instead, there is tons of overflow and you can't even see the first letter of any of the other columns.

Comment: I misunderstood your logic of `without overflow` as I thought you meant content should not go out of cells. Anyways, I have edited my answer and tried to give you a possible solution. Have a look.

Comment: Wow, this actually works! I didn't think it was possible! Thank you so much, you are awesome.

Comment: I gave you one - the downvote was someone else, I can do nothing about it :)

Comment: Just kidding. Not a big deal. :)

Answer (score 0):

`text-overflow` [applies to block containers](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#text-overflow), so it does not work properly on table-cell containers. You should wrap the text in a block container with a class like:

```
.ellip_wrap {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Edited:**

I refactored and removed following css:

```
.ellip_wrap:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}
.ellip_wrap:hover span {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```css
.table_wrap {
  width: 250px;
}
.table_item {
  table-layout: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.ellip_wrap {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="table_wrap">
  <table class="table_item" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th><div class="ellip_wrap">Short Header</div></th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><div class="ellip_wrap">Quite Long Header</div></th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><div class="ellip_wrap">MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMassiveHeader</div></th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I gave it a shot https://jsfiddle.net/uneuz22w/ - maybe I did something wrong (if so, please correct me) but this also doesn't quite work. The `th` containing `div.ellip_wrap` expands to fill the whole container `div`, so the table as a whole overflows. I would like the entire table to fit inside the container `div`.

Comment: In response to your edit, it's still not what I'm looking for. There is a ton of extra whitespace in the second column while parts of the first column are hidden. I want the second column to shrink as much as it can without overflowing, and then the rest of the space should be used for the first column, which can overflow if necessary. I'm thinking maybe it's not possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  border:1px solid green;
}

table {
  white-space: nowrap;
  table-layout: fixed;/* added this*/
  width: 100%;/* added this*/
}

th {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Short Header</th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Quite Long Header</th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMassiveHeader</th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div style="width:300px">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Short Header</th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Quite Long Header</th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMassiveHeader</th>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div style="width:300px">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Short Header</th>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Quite Long Header</th>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMassiveHeader</th>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div style="width:240px">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Short Header</th>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Quite Long Header</th>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMassiveHeader</th>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to quite work. For example https://i.imgur.com/smcjWgJ.png look at the first table, there is a ton of extra whitespace in the second column while parts of the first column are hidden. As I wrote in my post, "I just want all the columns except the first to shrink as much as possible without overflow, and for the first to column expand as much as it can while keeping the table inside the parent div while hiding any overflow of its contents with an ellipsis at the end."

Comment: @dumbmatter in this case i don't think it's possible with table :) this is against how table works, so not sure we can force things ... by the way are you obliged to use table ?

Comment: You're probably right about it not being possible, I was just being optimistic by asking the question :). I guess I don't need it to be a table, but I do need it to display tabular data (multiple rows, where each row has columns of the same size, and some of those sizes are dynamic based on content). If it's not possible to do with a table, I'd still be interested in how to do it without a table, although that would make it harder to use on my site.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri but you will never meet all the condition that's why it's a bit non-doable to force thing with table, there is better ways i guess;) https://jsfiddle.net/adfcceca/3/